# Type error when calling sdlttf.TTF_OpenFont() with the pysdl2 Python bindings

Tags: python, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I have all dependencies correctly installed (SDL2, SDL2_TTF, pysdl2).
I've tried to provide just the filename for the font and I've tried to hard code the full path. The font is in the same directory as the python file.

```
import sys
try:
    from sdl2 import *
    import sdl2.ext as sdl2ext
    import sdl2.sdlttf as sdlttf
except ImportError:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)


def run():
    sdl2ext.init()
    sdlttf.TTF_Init()
    RESOURCES = sdl2ext.Resources(__file__, "")
    # print(RESOURCES.get_path("arial.ttf"))
    font = sdlttf.TTF_OpenFont(RESOURCES.get_path("arial.ttf"), 24)
    window = sdl2ext.Window("SDL_TTF test", size=(800, 600))
    message = sdlttf.TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Hello World", (255, 255, 255))
    window.show()
    running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        window.refresh()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sdl2_test.py", line 32, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "sdl2_test.py", line 17, in run
    font = sdlttf.TTF_OpenFont(RESOURCES.get_path("arial.ttf"), 24)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it. Since I'm using Python 3 the type is incorrect due to the standard type used for representing strings in Python 3. I solved it by using str.encode()